# Bitwise Operator Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, bitwise-operators

I have a table that contains binary values such as:

```
binaryid    description
1           description1
2           description2
4           description3
8           description4
```

And I have another table that contains values:

```
DBID BinaryTogether
1    15
1    12
1     6
```

With the bitwise operator I want to get a table that would contain the following:

```
DBID   BinaryTogether BitwiseResult
1      15             description1,description2,description3,description4
1      12             description3,description4
1       6             description2, description3
```

Comment: You asked [exactly the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37575033/479863) a couple hours ago and deleted it. Again, have you tried anything or read [the fine manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions.html) and not understood something?

Answer (score 1):

You can join those tables using `&` bitwise operator and then aggregate descriptions using `string_agg` function. Here is example:

```
with 
  b(x,d) as (
    values
      (1,'description1'),
      (2,'description2'),
      (4,'description3'),
      (8,'description4')),
  p(y) as (
    values
      (15),
      (12),
      (6))
select
  y,
  string_agg(d,',')
from
  p join b on (x & y != 0)
group by
  y
```